# Selecting specific days of week within time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select records that occurred on Sun, Mon, Wed between 0:00 and 1:00. The dow part of this request is working but the 'hour' part does not seem to be included in the query. What have I done wrong? I feel like I am missing some parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE date_part('dow',date)=0 
    OR date_part('dow',date)=1 
    OR date_part('dow',date)=3 
    AND date_part('hour',date)<=1 
    AND date_part('hour',date)>= 0
```

Comment: So put some in.  I would start with parentheses around the OR conditions, since they all work together.

Comment: `OR` conditions need to be in  parenthesis, since `AND` has a higher precedence.

Comment: Right, you don't want that last OR and the first AND executing first.  Just try it, man.

Comment: `date` is rather a poor name for a SQL column (it's a key word), and doubly dubious because the column appears to be a TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: ok... makes sense now.. AND comes before parenthesis  - SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_part('hour',date)<=1 AND date_part('hour',date)>= 0 AND (date_part('dow',date)=0 OR date_part('dow',date)=1 OR date_part('dow',date)=3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (date_part('dow',date) In(0,1,3)) AND (date_part('hour',date)<=1 AND date_part('hour',date)>= 0)
```

Comment: Very elegant with the IN().  I would add you can simplify further.
`AND date_part(hour, date) BETWEEN 0 AND 1`;  Note that BETWEEN .. AND is not the same as BOOL AND BOOL.